# Use grep on stdin

Tags: c, grep, stdin, file-descriptor

So, I have used fork()
where the parent is opening a file and reading its contents into a buffer and sending the buffer from the write-end (fd[1]) to the read end (fd[0])

The child process is responsible for reading in the buffer. I want to redirect whatever is in fd[0] to stdin, so I can use Unix commands on it. To give an example:

```
// in child process
dup2(fd[0], 0); // 0 is STDIN 

// Don't know what to do here

execl("/bin/grep/", "grep", "hello", NULL); // find the string 'hello' and operate on the content coming from stdin
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be quite OK.
Maybe you could close some fds after `dup2`:

```
// in child process
dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
close(fd[0]);
close(fd[1]);
```

EDIT:

There seems to be typo: `"/bin/grep/"`

It should be: `"/bin/grep"`

Comment: That doesn't work either. I'm already closing fd[1] before I call dup2() and then I close fd[0] before the child exits, but that didn't work either.